# Getting a weird 500 error with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-500

Im trying to call PHP with ajax but it throws me 500, any ideas?

I get error code 500 for the file ajax is trying to load!

This code is retrieving data from Google Statistics - Im showing statistics on my site which is fetched if button is pressed via ajax.

**PHP Im calling with ajax:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_rs_ajax_statistics', 'rs_ajax_statistics');
function rs_ajax_statistics() {

try {
  $optParams = array();

    // Required parameter
    $metrics    = 'ga:uniquePageviews';
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime('-10 years'));
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d');

    //Current page path
    $path_name = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $optParams['filters'] = 'ga:pagePath==' . $path_name;

    $result = $analytics->data_ga->get( $analytics_id,
            $start_date,
            $end_date, $metrics, $optParams);

    // Everything is OK
    if( $result->getRows() ) {
        $views_overall = $result->getRows()[0][0];
        echo $views_overall;
    }
} 
// Something is wrong
catch(Exception $e) {
    //echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
} 
}
```

**Ajax call:**

```
    //Statistics
    var statistics = $('a.statistics');
    var statisticsMessage = $('div.meta-extra');


        statistics.click(function() {

                console.log('Great!');

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: ajaxURL,
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        'action': 'rs_ajax_statistics'
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        statisticsMessage.html(msg);
                    },
                    error: function() {

                    }
                }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log the error you get back in your ajax call

```
error:function (errorcode, errormsg) {
    console.log (errorcode + ' ' + errormsg);
}
```

**Edit**
The final answer is:
You should always switch error reporting on and solve the errors displayed.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

When using require you should use an absolute path. 
If it's in your application root you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get your absolute path. Otherwise you can use `realpath($relative_path)` see http://php.net/realpath.

Comment: I think I have to forget this question. Problem seems to be that Google authentication doesn't work with ajax.. Not sure why & I doubt I find anyone who have worked with so specific APIs in near future.

Comment: You should be able to authenticate yourself via ajax at Google services. An ajax call  is a normal http request.

Comment: It seems that I can't use  `require_once()` to get `google-api-php-client` & I get `PHP Fatal error`. I can't authenticate without it because it has few classes I need in my authentication code.. Is `require_once()` usually usable in ajax?

Comment: Yes it is a normal call like you would do with your browser. What happens when you try the url in your browser?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'https://www.blabla.com/rest-of-the-CORRECT-url' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php54/share/pear') in ...` This is the error I get with ajax. Exact same code works in browser without any problems.

Comment: Are you sure you get no error messages or are they turned off? Because usually it's an error in the required file. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Only error I get is the one I wrote in my last comment.. It's from error log. Like I said, it's working perfectly with normal browser request.

Comment: Sure! `require_once( 'wp-content/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php' );`

Comment: Ah ok try to set an absolute path instead of a relative.You could try `require_once(__DIR__ .  'wp-content/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php' );` if it's in the same directory and your php >= 5.3. Or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which contains the path to your applications root dir.

Comment: I can't use `__dir__ .` because I have it in different path but I hardcoded `/www/apache/domains/` etc & it worked!! Only problem is that if it's a security risk if I have whole path hardcoded?

Comment: If you feel better you could use `realpath('./../[../]wp-content/and-so-on)` see http://php.net/realpath